# Combining related organisation records in SQL where there is a Parent-Child relationship between organisations

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to build a table of data for use in Yellowfin BI reporting. One limitation of this is that no temporary tables can be created and then dropped in the database. I am pulling the data from an existing database, which i have no control over. I can only use SQL to query the existing data.

There are two tables in the source database i need to work with. I've simplified them for clarity. The first contains organisations. It has an ORG_ID column which contains a unique ID for each organisation and a PARENT_ORG_ID column indicating which organisation is the Parent Company of others in the list:

```
ORG_ID     PARENT_ORG_ID
1          Null
2          1
3          5
4          5
5          Null
6          1
```

Using the table above i can see that there are the following relationships between organisations:

```
ORG_ID     RELATED_ORGANISATIONS
1          2 and 6
2          1 and 6
3          5 and 4
4          5 and 3
5          4 and 3
6          1 and 2
```

I'm not sure the best way to represent these connections in a query as i need to use these relationships with a second table.

The second table i have is a list of organisations and money owed:

```
ORG_ID     MONEY_OWED
1          5
2          10
3          0
4          15
5          20
6          5
```

What i need to achieve is a table that i can search for any single ORG_ID, and see the combined data for that Organisation and all related Organisations. In the case of my example, this could be a results table something like this:

```
ORG_ID     MONEY_OWED_BY_ALL_RELATED_ORGS
1          20
2          20
3          35
4          35
5          35
6          20
```

I'm thinking i should use a CTE to handle the relationships between organisations but i can't get my head around it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can your hierarchies exceed one level of depth?

Comment: @GordonLinoff The hierarchies could exceed one level in depth. They don't currently, but it would be nice to find a solution that has the resilience to deal with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your particular example, you can use:

```
select o.*,
       sum(mo.money_owed) over (partition by coalesce(o.parent_org_id, o.org_id)) as parent_owed
from organizations o left join
     money_owed mo
     on mo.org_id = o.org_id;
```

This works because your organizations are only one level deep -- which is consistent with your sample data.